# Concat lists from dictionary-values to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<int, list<T>>` and want to get an `IEnumerable<T>`, that allows me to iterate over all elements of all lists in the dict. This should of course avoid coping all elements and other performance costly operations.

My approach with Linq, that is not quite right:

```
IEnumerable<T> enumerable = dict.SelectMany(list).Foreach(list.ConcatAll()).ToEnum();
```

If `Linq` is not the optimal way, please suggest other options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use the following code

```cs
var enumerable = dict.Values.SelectMany(v => v);
```

You are accessing the [`Values`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=netframework-4.8) collection of dictionary and then use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) method to project every value as `List<T>` and flatten to the resulting enumeration

Your code doesn't work because `SelectMany()` accepts `Func` as collection selector, there is also no need to use `Foreach` method. `ToEnum()` method usage isn't a valid here as well, it belongs to `Enum` type and almost all `System.Linq` methods already accept or return `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Beat me to it +1 for better explanation

Comment: When I iterate this resulting enum, will it iterate the lists or the elements of the lists?

Comment: @Mechandrius it should iterate for elements

Comment: @Mechandrius it'll iterate the elements of the list. `SelectMany` projects elements from every list to one resulting enumeration

Comment: Ok, this is the correct answer. Excuse me for asking such a simple question.